# Use base class's property/attribute as a table column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties, sqlalchemy

A game engine provides me with a `Player` class with a `steamid` property (coming from C++, this is just a basic example on what it would look like in Python):

```
# game_engine.py

class Player:

    def __init__(self, steamid):
        self.__steamid = steamid

    @property
    def steamid(self):
        return self.__steamid
```

I then proceed to subclass this class while adding a `gold` attribute:

```
# my_plugin.py

class MyPlayer(game_engine.Player, Base):
    gold = Column(Integer)
```

Now I need to store the player's `gold` to a database with the player's `steamid` as a primary key to identify the player. How do I tell SQLAlchemy to use the base class's `steamid` property as the primary key?

Here's something silly I tried:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

import game_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Player(game_engine.Player, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    _steamid = game_engine.Player.steamid

    @hybrid_property
    def steamid(self):
        return type(self)._steamid.__get__(self)
```

But yeah, it was a long shot...

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Player|player could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'player'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simpler than you might expect. The solution below is roughly equivalent to the one from r-m-n, but more straightforward because it uses modern declarative mapping. There is no need for `@hybrid_property`, you can just inherit `steamid` from the parent class.

```
# my_plugin.py

class MyPlayer(game_engine.Player, Base):

    def __init__(self, steamid, gold):
        super().__init__(steamid)
        self._id = self.steamid
        self.gold = gold

    _id = Column('steamid', Integer, primary_key=True)
    gold = Column(Integer)
```

Comment: I feel like this solution is the "proper" way to do this so I accepted it, but I will *personally* end up using r-m-n's answer, which is why I felt like giving him the +100 rep. I hope this is along SO's guidelines...

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the guidelines, but it's your bounty so you can spend it how you want. Most important is that you award the bounty at all, and you did. I'm still grateful for the accept.

Comment: On second thought, could you clarify why you expect to use r-m-n's solution? To me, it seems like self-punishment...

Answer (score 1):

this could be done using [classical mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


class MyPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, steamid, gold):
        super().__init__(steamid)
        self.gold = gold
        self._steamid = super().steamid


player = Table('player', Base.metadata,
    Column('_steamid', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('gold', Integer),
)


mapper(MyPlayer, player)
```

Comment: This works, but it is more complicated than necessary. You can get the same result with a declarative mapping and without using `@hybrid_property`; see my answer.

Comment: It appears that I was wrong and `super().steamid` actually *does* work (only not for setters), so I can just get rid of the `self._steamid = super().steamid` and use `def steamid(self): return super().steamid` as a `hybrid_property` instead! I will also end up using classical mapping *anyways* due to huge amount of not-so-compliant code, so thanks for the answer! :) I didn't accept yours since I feel like the other answer from @Julian is more "proper" way to do it, but yours helped me this time more so I gave you the 100 rep bounty.

Comment: On second glance, it seems that you're not even using the `hybrid_property` in this answer. Was that a mistake?

Comment: The `hybrid_property` is contributing absolutely nothing in this answer. Without it, `MyPlayer.steamid` would still return the exact same value and everything else would behave exactly the same as well.

Comment: Yes, `hybrid_property` is unnecessary here.

Comment: No. What are you trying to achieve with `hybrid_property`?